# I cannot add Multiple data into my list<string>

Tags: c#, list

I have the following list:

```
List<string> department = new List<string>();
```

Add the data one by one is working but I cannot push the multiple data into the list:

```
using System;

namespace Linq_Basics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<names> names = new List<names>();
            names.Add(new names { Firstname = "viki", Lastname = "Amar" });
            names.Add(new names { Firstname = "Sankar", Lastname = "Pandi" });
            names.Add(new names { Firstname = "Bala", Lastname = "Murugan" });
            foreach (var v in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Firstname is {0} and the last name is {1}", v.Firstname, v.Lastname);
            }
            List<string> department = new List<string>();
            department.Add(new List<string> { "ece", "cse" });
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class names
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to add sequence of strings to list of strings:

```
department.AddRange(new List<string> { "ece", "cse" });
```

Or simply call `Add` twice to avoid new list creation:

```
department.Add("ece");
department.Add("cse");
```

Or use [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) if you want to hold only these two strings in department list:

```
var department = new List<string> { "ece", "sce" };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> department = new List<string> { "ece", "cse" };
```

Answer (score 0):

`department` defines a list which holds the `string` type. You are trying to add a `List<string>` to it instead of a `string`:

```
 List<string> department = new List<string>();
 department.Add(new List<string> { "ece", "cse" });
```

Needs to be:

```
department.Add("ece")
//etc...
```

Or:

```
department = new List<string>() { "ece", "cse" };
```

Or:

```
department.AddRange(new List<string> { "ece", "cse" });
```